# Android XML-RPC Error

Tags: java, android, xml-rpc

I'm trying  to call this XML-RPC Method from Android(http://foxrate.org/) using this libraries https://github.com/timroes/aXMLRPC

The call code is:

```
        XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(new URL("http://www.foxrate.org/rpc/"));
    try {
        Object o = client.call("foxrate.currencyConvert", "USD","GBP",(double)1);
    } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It generates a correct XML call, but the server returns Http error code 301. 
When I try to do this call from firefox with POSTER plug-in it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP 301 status code means, that the server wants to forward to another URL.

In this case it wants to take away the "www" and redirects to foxrate.org/rpc.

If you want the aXMLRPC client to follow this redirects (what it doesn't in its default mode), use the [`FLAGS_FORWARD` flag](https://github.com/timroes/aXMLRPC#flags_forward). The first line of your code should look like this:

```
XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(new URL("http://www.foxrate.org/rpc/"), FLAGS_FORWARD);
```

You will find more flags -- for the case something else happens (like invalid SSL certificates ;)) -- in the [documentation](https://github.com/timroes/aXMLRPC/blob/master/README.md).

Of course, you could also use http://foxrate.org/rpc directly as URL, but that would be too simple :) (And they might change it later to some other redirect.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/

It is quite good and worked very well for me.